# How to add dynamically Buttons to div

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Array of text, that generates Buttons(see in the Code example) and the generated Buttons should then be added to a div and not to the body.

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
        //let list = ["A","B","C"];
        let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PrüfungenName"));
        let listBtns = [];
        let listPs = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                var button = document.createElement("button");
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerHTML = "nicht durchgeführt";
                p.id = "p " + i;

                button.innerHTML = list[i];
                button.name = list[i];
                button.id = "Button " + i;

                button.labels = list[i];
                listBtns[i] = button;

                listPs[i] = p;
                button.addEventListener("click", OpenAndLoad());
                document.getElementById("AddedButtons").appendChild(button);
                document.getElementById("AddedButtons").appendChild(p);
            }
    </script>

    <div id="AddedButtons"></div>
```

**Error Message**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>       at ""

When trying `document.body.appenChild(button)` it works, but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you script after the div. The div will not be present at the time yoir script is executed. Alternatively add a funtion around your script that executes when the [dom is ready.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)